# Error when using statsmodels with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, statsmodels

I'm having problems with PyInstaller and `statsmodels`. When I run the executable I got the error `ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels.__init__.tools'`, when I run the code directly with Python everything works normally.

I have tried [this solution](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2183#issuecomment-449936889).

It works for the `tools` module, but I got another error:
[image: __init__._version]

I have try to add the `statsmodels`,`statsmodels.__init__` and `statsmodels.__init__._version`, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) is one of the complex modules for PyInstaller and that is because it depends on some other modules that they would mess the PyInstaller import graph. My solution might not look optimized but would do the job.

[`hidden-imports`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports) would only tell PyInstaller to look for that module but sometimes it can't trace module dependencies (like DLLs, external py files, etc.). so for `statsmodels` it won't help.

The overall procedure is to first tell PyInstaller to don't trace `statsmodels` with [`exclude-module`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) and feed the module manually to the final executable.
Also, we need to bundle some modules like (`numpy`, `pandas`, etc) with [`Tree`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes) class.

I'm using Python 3.7.4 with latest PyInstaller 3.5.
Suppose below example taken from [official docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html#minimal-examples).

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
dat = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Guerry", "HistData").data
results = smf.ols('Lottery ~ Literacy + np.log(Pop1831)', data=dat).fit()
print(results.summary())
```

Use below spec file (I'm using Python's [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) called `env` next to the script)

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['script.py'],
             pathex=['<root_project_path>'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['six', 'fractions', 'csv', 'pytz', 'timeit'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['statsmodels'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/statsmodels", prefix="statsmodels")
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/numpy", prefix="numpy")
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/pandas", prefix="pandas")
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/scipy", prefix="scipy")
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/dateutil", prefix="dateutil")
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/patsy", prefix="patsy")

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='script',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

And finally generate your executable with:

```
pyinstaller script.spec
```